# Probability of picking a particular number from array

Tags: c#, .net, math, probability

I'm scratching my head for 2 days and can't figure out what's wrong with my code. Lets say that I have 2 arrays:

```
Array1[33]: 0..31 (it has 2 fives)
Array2[32]: 0..31 (it has one five)
```

Now I want to calculate the probability of randomly picking 5 from first array and 5 from second array. I do this with this formula:

```
(2M / 33) * (1M / 32)
```

which is roughly `0.001894`. Now, if I run the cycle long enough, say 1000,000,0 I should expect '5' '5' coming up roughly 18940 times, but this doesn't happen when I run the test. Here's the code:

```
public class Program
{
    private static List<int> numbers1 = new List<int>();
    static Random random = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
    private static List<int> numbers2 = new List<int>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++)
        {
            numbers1.Add(i);
            numbers2.Add(i);
        }

        numbers1.Add(5);

        while (true)
        {
            var counter = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
            {
                var num1 = numbers1[random.Next(0, 33)];
                var num2 = numbers2[random.Next(0, 32)];

                if (num1 == 5 && num2 == 5) counter++;
            }

            Console.Write(counter + ": " + (decimal) counter / 10000000 + " - " + (2M / 33) * (1M / 32));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The pattern '5' '5' comes up somewhere 9300-9500 times when it should come up twice as many times.

So my question is, what's wrong with my math/code?

Thanks

EDIT:

note that if I leave only one five in first array, everything works as expected.

```
    //numbers1.Add(5);

    while (true)
    {
        var counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            var num1 = numbers1[random.Next(0, 33)];
            var num2 = numbers2[random.Next(0, 32)];

            if (num1 == 5 && num2 == 5) counter++;
        }

        Console.Write(counter + ": " + (decimal) counter / 10000000 + " - " + (1M / 33) * (1M / 32));
        Console.ReadLine();
```

this code returns expected result

Comment: I wonder, is it the same result with two separate `Random`s?

Comment: @YoryeNathan yep, just tried it :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is quite simple: you are adding too many elements to the arrays.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++)
{
    numbers1.Add(i);
    numbers2.Add(i);
}
```

Adds **33** elements to the arrays not 32.

`Random.Next(a, b)` generates a random number between `[a, b)` (half-open interval). So `random.Next(0, 33)` will generate a number between 0 and 32 (inclusive). The additional 5 you add to `numbers1` is added will never be retrieved because it's at index 33.

So simple change the 33 to 32 when creating the data and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

Well, just looking at the code I didn't see it either. Turning on the debugger and inspecting a few things I notice that:

```
numbers1.Count == 34
```

You assume it is `33`. The double-five is the last element. It is never drawn.

That's why you should not write magic numbers such as in `random.Next(0, 33)`. Use `random.Next(0, numbers1.Count)` instead. This applies to other things in your code as well. Repeated constants are locations prone to bugs.

Comment: Which will allow him to select that last number, but then his percentages are slightly off because his arrays are one larger. The real problem is with his initialization code.

Comment: Yeah, right. It doesn't really matter. The problem is apparent now.

Answer (score 0):

Move your statement `var random = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());` outside of the while loop.

Re-seeding `Random` repeatedly within very close time intervals will give skewed results.

Seed `Random` only once for your process or you will get wonky results.

Comment: Remove everything within the init for Random and just call Random()

Comment: I updated the code. Random class is now declared as static and initialized once, but I get same result

Comment: Add this after line var num2 = ....

                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", num1, num2);
                Console.ReadKey();

and re-run.

Comment: thanks for your help, but random works properly, after every iteration, num1 and num2 are different numbers.

Comment: Did you mean to have the random range be different between your two arrays here?              var num1 = numbers1[random.Next(0, 33)];
            var num2 = numbers2[random.Next(0, 32)];

Comment: Yes, numbers1 has 33 numbers in it, from 0 to 32, but number 5 occurs twice in numbers1. numbers2 has 32 numbers in it, from 0 to 31